# ¿Guardar una fecha seleccionada dentro de un input (php) en una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```html
<td>
<input action="terminaVenta.php" value="" name="fecha_compra" class="form-control" required type="text">
</td>
```

```php
$compra = ($_POST["fecha_compra"]);

$sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("INSERT INTO compras(fecha, fecha_compra, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
$sentencia->execute([$fecha, $compra, $total]);
```

---

> ESTE SERIA EL HTML

```html
<?php

include_once "includes/header.php"; 
require "../../conexion.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION["carrito"])) $_SESSION["carrito"] = [];
$granTotal = 0;
?>
<div class="container-fluid"> 
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4"> 
        <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Salidas de almacen a unidades</h1>
        <a href="ventas.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
</div>




<div class="col-xs-12">

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET["status"])) {
        if ($_GET["status"] === "1") {
    ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>¡Correcto!</strong> Venta realizada correctamente
            </div>
        <?php
        } else if ($_GET["status"] === "2") {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Venta cancelada</strong>
            </div>
        <?php
        } else if ($_GET["status"] === "3") {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                <strong>Ok</strong> Producto quitado de la lista
            </div>
        <?php
        } else if ($_GET["status"] === "4") {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <strong>Error:</strong> El producto que buscas no existe
            </div>
        <?php
        } else if ($_GET["status"] === "5") {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Error: </strong>El producto está agotado
            </div>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Error:</strong> Algo salió mal mientras se realizaba la venta
            </div>
    <?php
        }
    }


    
    ?>
    <br>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="awesomplete.base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="awesomplete.theme.css">
    <form method="post" action="agregarAlCarrito.php">
        <label for="codigo">Código de producto:</label>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="codigo" required type="text" id="codigo" placeholder="Escribe el código">
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Fecha de la factura</th>
                <th>Existencia</th>
                <th>Unidad de Medida</th>
                <th>Observaciones</th>

                <!--<th>Precio de venta</th>
                
                <th>Total</th>-->
                <th>Quitar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
            <?php foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $indice => $producto) {
                $granTotal += $producto->total;
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $producto->id ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $producto->codigo ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $producto->descripcion ?></td>
                    <!--<td><?php //echo $producto->precioVenta ?></td>-->
                    <td>
                        <form action="cambiar_cantidad.php" method="post">
                            <input name="indice" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $indice; ?>">
                            <input min="1" name="cantidad" class="form-control" required type="number" step="0.1" value="<?php echo $producto->cantidad; ?>">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input  value="" name="fecha_compra" class="form-control" type="date">
                    </td>
                    <!--<td><?php //echo $producto->total ?></td>-->
                    <td><?php echo $producto->existencia ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $producto->unidad_medida ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $producto->observaciones ?></td>
                    
                    
                    
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo "quitarDelCarrito.php?indice=" . $indice ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

    <!--<h3>Total: <?php //echo $granTotal; ?></h3>-->
    <form action="./terminarVenta.php" method="POST">
        <input name="total" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $granTotal; ?>">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Terminar Transacción</button>
        <a href="./cancelarVenta.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar Transacción</a>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<script src="awesomplete.minn.js"></script>
        <script src="scriptsss.js"></script>
    
        <?php include_once "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

> ESTAS SERIAN LAS SENTENCIAS

```
include_once "base_de_datos.php";
```

include "includes/functions.php";

$fecha= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$compra = date("Y-m-d", $_POST["fecha_compra"]);

$sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("INSERT INTO compras(fecha, fecha_compra, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
$sentencia->execute([$fecha, $compra, $total]);

Comment: El elemento `input` no tiene el atributo `action`. Ver en la documentación [cómo crear un formulario](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). Aparentemente la parte de PHP está bien, tendrías que mostrar más información, tanto de html como php, para ver si hay problemas.

Comment: tu html esta mal codificado, o simplemente no nos estas mostrando lo que falta del codigo, pero el action no va en el input, iria en la etiqueta <form> y te faltaria el submit